# Template type object constructed in class C++

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

How can I do something like this? I want to create a object of class C and use parameters. To elaborate, the error here is the compiler reads this as a conversion, instead of me creating an object with parameters.

EDIT: for those who still don't understand, `foobar` is irrelevant. I've removed it as the error still occurs without the function.

```
// define foobar else where
template <class C>
class Dummy {
    void foo(int bar) {
        C dumdum = C(bar); // Error - '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from initializer-list to 'C'
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [variadic templates and parameter packs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)?

Comment: How does that help me?

Comment: This doesnt seem to be valid C++, foobar is not declared anywhere.

Comment: `foobar` is irrelevant. The question asks how I can create an object of template type with parameters. I'm just using it in a function for example.

Comment: @Vality That's okay here since the argument is type-dependent, and `foobar` is therefore a dependent name.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04d42e5ba752fbd0  Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain why my question is not fit for StackOverflow? Ok, I'll see to fixing that.

Answer (score 0):

> How does that help me?

You can make `foo` a function template that accepts a parameter pack to make it general.

Example program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

template <class C>
class Dummy {
   public:
      template <typename... Args>
         void foo(Args... args ) {
            foobar(C(args...)); 
         }
};

struct Foo
{
   Foo(int, int) {}
};

struct Bar
{
   Bar(int) {}
};

struct Baz
{
};

void foobar(Foo)
{
   std::cout << "In foobar(Foo)\n";
}

void foobar(Bar)
{
   std::cout << "In foobar(Bar)\n";
}

void foobar(Baz)
{
   std::cout << "In foobar(Baz)\n";
}

int main()
{
   Dummy<Foo>().foo(10, 20);
   Dummy<Bar>().foo(10);
   Dummy<Baz>().foo();
}
```

Output:

```
In foobar(Foo)
In foobar(Bar)
In foobar(Baz)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @aschepler, the OP said *I want to create a object of class C and use parameters.* What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
C dumdum(bar);
```

Or:

```
C dumdum{bar};
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
class C {
public:
    C(int a) {}
};

template <class C>
class Dummy {
public:
    void foo(int bar) {
        C dumdum = C(bar); 
    }
};

int main() {
    Dummy<C> dummy;
    dummy.foo(2);
    return 0;
}
```

I didn't see any errors.